# Generating a Eulerian circuit of a complete graph with constant memory

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, graph-theory

(this question is about trying to use some combinatorics to simplify an algorithm and save memory)
Let $K_{2n+1}$ be a complete undirected graph on $2n+1$ vertices.
I would like to generate a Eulerian circuit of this graph (visit each edge exactly once).

One solution is to run the DFS-based algorithm that can find a Eulerian circuit in any Eulerian graph (a graph with all vertices of even degree).

However, I'm hoping it's possible to use the nice structure of $K_{2n+1}$ to avoid constructing the graph and running the algorithm. Is there a way to construct one such circuit in O(n) time with O(1) memory?

**Motivation**: The motivation behind this is an algorithm which receives a list L and needs to calculate $B(A(x), A(y))$ for each unordered pair ${x,y}$ of distinct elements of L (I'm only considering unordered pairs since $B(u,w)=B(w,u)$). The result of operation A is very large and takes almost half of the available memory. Such a circuit will allow me to minimize the number of calls to operation $A$.

**Note**: This is a sort of "undirected" version of generating a de-Bruijn sequence. I once heard it's possible to generate a de-Bruijn sequence with constant memory, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Number the vertices $1,2, \dots 2n+1$.

Consider the sequence $1, 2n, 2, 2n-1, 3, 2n-2, \dots, n,n+1$, ignore $2n+1$ at the moment.

This gives a hamiltonian path in $K_{2n}$.

Now add $1$ to each vertex $\mod 2n$, to get $2,1,3,2n,4, 2n-1 \dots, n+1, n+2$. This can be visualized as writing the numbers $1,2, \dots, 2n$ in a circle and rotating the path. (see figure below).

Repeat this process of adding $1$, $n$ times. This gives you a set of $n$ edge-disjoint hamiltonian paths in $K_{2n}$. (We can show that by proving that (wlog) $1$ is first adjacent to $2n$, then $2,3$, then $4,5$ etc)

To each of these paths, add $2n+1$ at the end and join back to the first vertex of the path.

This gives you an Euler tour of $K_{2n+1}$ which starts and ends at vertex $2n+1$.

This can be computed in constant memory.

Note that this basically follows the (classic/folklore) construction that $K_{2n+1}$ can be decomposed into $n$ edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles. See this for instance, [Modern Graph Theory, page 16](http://books.google.com/books?id=SbZKSZ-1qrwC&pg=PA16).

In case that book is not accessible, here is a snapshot of the relevant part of that page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a very nice and simple algorithm!

If someone is interested I implemented a python version that you can find [on GitHub](https://github.com/cglacet/clique-tour). I also implemented a tour that is (probably) not optimal for even sized cliques (for a $n$ node graph, $n/2$ edges appear twice). For now the code looks like this:

```
def build(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return almost_eulerian(n)
    else:
        return eulerian(n)

def eulerian(n):
    middle = (n-1)//2
    path_shape = [ u for i in range(middle) for u in (i,n-2-i) ]
    hamiltonian_paths = []

    # Increment the path shape to "rotate" the hamiltonian path 
    for i in range(middle):
        hamiltonian_paths += [ (path_shape[p]+i)%(n-1) for p in range(len(path_shape)) ]
        hamiltonian_paths += [n-1] # Everything is rotated, this node is here to make a junction from one hamiltonian path to the next

    # Close the tour
    hamiltonian_paths += [hamiltonian_paths[0]]
    return hamiltonian_paths

def almost_eulerian(n):
    path_shape = [ u for i in range(n//2) for u in (i,n-1-i) ]
    hamiltonian_paths = []
    for i in range(n//2):
        path = [ (path_shape[p]+i)%n for p in range(len(path_shape)) ]
        hamiltonian_paths += path
    hamiltonian_paths += [hamiltonian_paths[0]]
```